# Show all tables where two columns exist - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, search, where-clause

I want to a search for all tables that includes both of  'Documentversionid' and 'ClientMedicationID' columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.TABLE_NAME
FROM
(
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Documentversionid%'
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%ClientMedicationID%'
) t2
    ON t1.TABLE_NAME = t2.TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME  
FROM `information_schema`.`columns` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='<YOUR DATABASE>' AND 
   (`COLUMN_NAME` = 'Documentversionid' OR `COLUMN_NAME`='ClientMedicationID') 
GROUP BY `TABLE_NAME` HAVING COUNT > 1
```